# Suppress taskkill "success" window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I suppress the "success" window that appears after I restart app.exe?

```
cmd /c DisplaySwitch.exe /extend & taskkill /f /im app.exe & app.exe
```

Comment: which command is causing the window?

Comment: The taskkill command.

Comment: Taskkill doesn't generate a window after it successfully kills a process. I use it daily and I've never seen a window be created.

Comment: I get a window with `SUCCESS: The process "app.exe" with PID # has been terminated.`

Comment: you can use `start /min` to **minimize** the window in a batch file. If you really need to completely **hide** the window, there are many solutions out there on google.

Comment: @user2319146 You should redirect to device `NUL`. 


So you can write `taskkill /f /im app.exe>nul`

Comment: @Hackoo Oh wait. Is the script launched from the command line or a batch script? If it is launched from a batch script, there shouldn't be a window.

Comment: @Hackoo Appending `>nul` only clears the window; I still have to close it manually. @Hacking From the command line.

Comment: You'll get a message, not a new window. https://i.imgur.com/qwvkQnO.png It's likely a result of you using `cmd` to start a program instead of `start`.

Comment: Is there any special reason to launch new window? Isn't the current one enough? Also, do you want to completely hide new generated window?

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of this window?

Comment: `cmd /c DisplaySwitch.exe /extend & taskkill /f /im notepad.exe>nul 2>&1 & Start "" notepad.exe & taskkill /f /im cmd.exe`

Comment: @Hackoo `start ""` did the trick; thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like that :

```
cmd /c DisplaySwitch.exe /extend & taskkill /f /im notepad.exe>nul 2>&1 & Start "" notepad.exe & taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
```

Comment: `cmd /c DisplaySwitch.exe /extend & taskkill /f /im notepad.exe & start "" notepad.exe` was sufficient.